# inlining spread operator during declaration es2018

Tags: javascript, spread-syntax, ecmascript-2018

I want to do something like this:

```
const translations = {
    en: {
        statistics_title: 'Statistics'
    },
    ru: {
        statistics_title: 'Статистика'
    },
    uk: {
        ...ru
    }
}
```

obviously it doesn't work, of course, I can set another const, and then use it but I'm lazy ) so I'm curious if javascript allows you to do so?

Comment: No, you cannot do this as the object doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Spread properties are not part of ES6.

Answer (score 1):

You can't self reference in objects unless it's a method.

You could do:

```
const translations = {
    en: {
        statistics_title: 'Statistics'
    },
    ru: {
        statistics_title: 'Статистика'
    },
    get uk () {
        return this.ru
    }
}
```

**Edit**

If you want intending for `translations.uk` to not be a copy of `ru` and hold it's own data this way won't work. This just sets up `translations.uk` as a reference to `translations.ru`

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare this `ru` value before spreading, i.e.:

```
const ru = {
    statistics_title: 'Статистика'
};

const translations = {
    en: {
        statistics_title: 'Statistics'
    },
    ru,
    uk: {
        ...ru
    }
};
```

Comment: thanks, Getter makes a lot of sense, since you call it after the instantiation of the object.